# Sorting Python list with exception

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I sort a python list alphabetically, taking into consideration the numbering at the back of the list items. See example below and code used to sort.
Note that it is not possible to insert a zero into the code if the number is below 10.

**original list:**

> ['drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-7',
>   'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-4', 'drawing-n-9',
>   'drawing-n-8', 'drawing-n-16', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-14',
>   'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-12', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-10',
>   'drawing-n-17']

**Sorted list:**

> ['drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-10', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-12',
>   'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-14', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-16',
>   'drawing-n-17', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-4',
>   'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-7', 'drawing-n-8',
>   'drawing-n-9']

**Desired List output:**

> ['drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-4',
>   'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-7', 'drawing-n-8',
>   'drawing-n-9', 'drawing-n-10', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-12',
>   'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-14', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-16',
>   'drawing-n-17']

**Code:**

```
dwg_number_keys = [key for key in kwargs if key.startswith("drawing-n-")]
print dwg_number_keys
print sorted(dwg_number_keys, key=str.lower)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> my_list = ['drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-7', 'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-4', 'drawing-n-9', 'drawing-n-8', 'drawing-n-16', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-14', 'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-12', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-10', 'drawing-n-17']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda s:int(s[s.rindex('-')+1:]))
['drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-4', 'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-7', 'drawing-n-8', 'drawing-n-9', 'drawing-n-10', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-12', 'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-14', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-16', 'drawing-n-17']
```

The `key` lambda is just parsing the integer found at the last of each string after the '-' mark.

Answer (score 0):

Parse it from a string into an integer to sort on:-

```
>>> begin = len("drawing-n-")
>>> sorted(dwg_number_keys, key=lambda s:int(s[len("drawing-n-"):]))
['drawing-n-1', 'drawing-n-2', 'drawing-n-3', 'drawing-n-4', 'drawing-n-5', 'drawing-n-6', 'drawing-n-7', 'drawing-n-8', 'drawing-n-9', 'drawing-n-10', 'drawing-n-11', 'drawing-n-12', 'drawing-n-13', 'drawing-n-14', 'drawing-n-15', 'drawing-n-16', 'drawing-n-17']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you want if the format is as consistent as you made it out to be

`lambda x: int(x.split('-')[-1])`